# How are the FPR and FNR estimated for a new diagnostic test?

Tags: statistics, test, diagnostics

Let's consider a case of a test for presence/absence of a viral infection. When we have certainty as to whether a specific individual is carrying the virus, it is easy to estimate the False Positive Rate (FPR) and the False Negative rate (FNR) of a new diagnostic test. However, I suspect that for many real case scenarios, we cannot have certainty. In such case, I can think of two general (non-exclusive) solutions to estimate the FPR and the FNR of a test.

- Cross validation with same test
- Cross validation with other test (such other test may include a boundary threshold based on symptoms and signs)

Are there other techniques to estimate FPR and FNR of a diagnostic test? In general, could you point me to a source that discuss such techniques?

Comment: If you look through the literature there are some theoretical papers on that e.g. https://doi.org/10.2307/2530508 but I don't remember ever seeing anything like that done in practice e.g. in a submission to the FDA.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167587700001173 (some 20 years later) has some demonstrative application.